# using awk to split a string, then piece together columns 3-n

Tags: bash, awk, split, delimiter, dynamic-columns

I don't often write bash scripts so forgive my ignorance.  I have a log file that I read line-by-line.  Depending on the first 4 characters, I manipulate the string and rewrite to a cleaned-up file.  In rare cases, I don't know how many columns there will be.  Initially, I used the following, before realizing there were more than 7 columns farther down in the 20,000+ line log file:

```
echo $line | awk '{split($0,a," "); print a[3] " " a[4] " " a[5] " " a[6] " " a[7]}' >> $filename
```

…producing output like:  `Hello world, I need vacation`

I'm at the point where I can extract all desired info, but it writes as a list:

```
echo $line | awk '{split($0,a," "); for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) print a[i]}' >> $filename
```

…producing:

```
Hello  
world,  
I  
need  
vacation
```

Using the post "Using awk to print all columns from the nth to the last" (among others), I've tried throwing a cat, svn, plus other things into the mix but am not getting the syntax right.  I like the thought of replacing the awk part above with:

```
awk '{out=""; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){out=$out" "$i}; print $out}'
```

but I apparently don't understand the rules.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `printf("%s", out); }` # end for loop . Next line `printf("\n")`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

What about `cut` instead:

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5" | cut -d ' ' -f 3-
```

Output:

```
3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted yesterday but it was deleted before I could get back to hit the check mark (thank you, stranger!).  Using awk, the post said:

awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", $i,(i==NF?RS:FS)}' <<< "$line" >> "$filename"

with explanation: (i==NF?RS:FS) is a ternary test condition -- if last field, use RS (Record Separator & newline, by default); else use FS (Field Separator, with whitespace as default).